# External arrows for jcarousel?

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I'm creating a slideshow with jcarousel.

So far, my slideshow uses most of the defaults for a horizontal slideshow with the tango theme.

Can I add an extra "next" and "previous" arrows?

I'd like to have them outside of the slideshow container.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [jcarousel example.](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_controls.html)

If you want to hide the default buttons, you can pass `null` in your configuration to the `buttonNextHTML` and `buttonPrevHTML` properties, then using the `initCallback`, you can make any Elements on your page the next and previous buttons.